# Hide image in load time and display based one url parameter value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This page has images and these images must be hidden in load time, after the page receives parameter value from another aspx page(without clicking any button), an image shows based one parameter value. This code can receive data successfully but how to use parameter value to hide and show an image?

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" id="mybutton" />
 <script>
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'About.aspx',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = $.trim(data);
            if (result = 2) {
                $("image1").show();

            } else {

                if (result = 3) {

                    $("image2").show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>

   <div id="graphic">
    <img id="gate1" src="Img/Fully Close Green.png" />
    <img id="gate2" src="Img/Fully Close Red.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code hide the images on `document ready` event or set `display:none` using css class and then user id of images with `image1` and `image2`, the `#` tag is used to access id of any element and `.` used for class for more chcek [This](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):-

```
$(function () {
$('#graphic img').hide();
$.ajax({
    url: 'About.aspx',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        var result = $.trim(data);
        if (result == 2) {
            $("#gate1").show();

        } else if (result == 3) {
            $("#gate2").show();
        }
        //you can put more options here or just use else condition instread of else if
    }
});
});
```

Comment: still displays all images? how to settle that?

Comment: well this code working fine and hidding all images on load http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/30/ may be you have some other code showing  them

Comment: this code can hide the images but the expected result of displaying an image based parameter value is not working?

Comment: can you try to alert result what its comming are you sure its 1 or 2?>

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect comparison logic. Use `==` or `===` instead of just `=`.

Also, study [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Use the elements' IDs.

```
if (result == 2) {
   $("#gate1").show();
} else {
   if (result == 3) {
      $("#gate2").show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to hide all & show only the one matched with the "result" value?

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'About.aspx',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = $.trim(data);
            // Hide all
            $('div#graphic img').hide();

            // Show matched one
            $('#gate' + result).show();
        }
    });
});
```